# Java Android OutputStreamWriter write() not passing parameters to php file

Tags: java, php, android, parameters

I'm very new to android programming and I have a problem with OutputStreamWriter. Now, I'm working on a simple test application to send POST requests to a server. There is a PHP application on the server-side, which is designed to write data in a MYSQL database. When I run my android app it accesses the PHP file correctly but the parameters are not passed.

I have been conductive an extensive search over all types of forums and tried some of the answers given, but nothing worked for me. What am I doing wrong?

**PHP**

```php
<?$conecta = mysqli_connect('localhost','username','password','killerbees');
if (!$conecta) {echo "Unable to verify nickname. Please, try again later!";}
else
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM KillerBees WHERE nickname = '" . addslashes($_POST['kbfnickname']) . "'";                                                                    
    if ($resultado = mysqli_query($conecta,$sql))
    {
        if (mysqli_num_rows($resultado) == 0)
        {       
            $sql = "INSERT INTO KillerBees (nickname, password, level, seconds) VALUES ('" . addslashes($_POST['kbfnickname']) . "', '" . addslashes($_POST['kbfpassword']) . "', 0, 0)";
                   $resultado = mysqli_query($conecta,$sql);
                   $_SESSION['nickname'] = $_POST['kbfnickname'];
                   $_SESSION['level'] = 0;
                   $_SESSION['seconds'] = 0; 
                   echo "form_register";
        }
        else 
        {
            $linha = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);
            if ($linha['password']==stripslashes($_POST['kbfpassword']))
            {
                $file = glob("users/".$_POST['kbfnickname']."*");
                $_SESSION['nickname'] = $_POST['kbfnickname'];
                $_SESSION['level'] = $linha['level'];
                $_SESSION['seconds'] = $linha['seconds'];
                if (sizeof($file)!=0 and $linha['email']!="")  
                {
                    echo "form_game";
                }
                else  
                {
                    echo "form_register";
                }                     
            }
            else
            {
                echo "The combination nickname/password doesn't exist in our database.";               
            }
        }
    }    
    else 
    {
        echo "Unable to verify nickname. Please, try again later!";

    }
    if ($conecta) mysqli_close($conecta);
}?>
```

**ANDROID JAVA**

```java
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        try{
            String nickname = arg0[0];
            String password = arg0[1];
            String link="https://savvyartstudio.com/killerbees/signin.php";
            String urlParameters  = URLEncoder.encode("kbfnickname", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(nickname, "UTF-8");
            urlParameters += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("kbfpassword", "UTF-8") + "=" +  URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8");
            URL url = new URL(link);
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
            wr.write(urlParameters);
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new  InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            line = reader.readLine();
            sb.append(line);
            reader.close();

            return sb.toString();
        } catch(Exception e){
            return "Unable to verify nickname. Please, try again later!";
        }

}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `return "Unable to verify nickname. Please, try again later!";` No. You dont know that. There can be other causes. Better:   `return "Exception: " + e.getMessage();`. Do you get that exception? Or else what do you get as echo? What does doInBackground() return?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements. You need to fix it as soon as possible.

Comment: @blackapps it returns the first echo "form_register" which is the one I am looking for; but, when I go to the database I see the record was inserted with nickname and password blank

Comment: @Dharman, yes, I realize that but this is only a test not the actual code I will implement

Comment: Maybe I should have added the following: the record is added to the database but with nickname and password blank

Comment: You should check if the parameters are there and start to echo them to see their value: `  echo "form_register: $_POST['kbfnickname'])....$_POST['kbfpassword']";` or something like that. Echo the received partameters back.

Comment: Also use the isset() function to see if a parameter is set. if ( isset($_POST['kbfpassword']) echo ( ........) else echo ( ......) .

Comment: @blackapps I already check that and in fact, they have no value

Comment: Please adapt your php code so we can see what you do. Checking if parameters are set should be the first thing you do. You post all kind of sql code which in fact is irrelevant when the problem is passing parameter values.

Comment: Please remove the `wr.close();`

Comment: @blackapps I simplified the code to: <?
echo "nickname: " . $_POST['kbfnickname'] . ", password: " . $_POST['kbfpassword'];
?>

Comment: @blackapps but still doesn't work, the result is `nickname: ,  password:`

Comment: furthermore, removing wr.close() didn't alter anything

Comment: Use the var_dump($_POST); command to see if anything is posted. At receiving side read all lines. Now you only read the first one.

Comment: Ehhhh if you use $_POST['item'] and that item does not exist then you will get an error i think. I conclude that at sending side the strings are empty. And use php isset() function to check if a parameter is present. Empty or not.

Comment: @blackapps the result is NULL on both sides :)

Comment: @blackapps So, I did the tests as suggested and: $_POSTs are in fact not assigned when I check with isset() and at sending side both strings contain values; so, back to square 1

Comment: Have you tried var_dump()?

Comment: @blackapps yes I did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

guys
Thank you all for your help. After two days of trying to solve my problem, I was only able to solve it by changing to the $_GET method; the $_POST method didn't work for me, at all.

I used the $_GET method explained here. https://gist.github.com/hitenpratap/8e1f28d60c0bb11a5bca